# Sending an email using Google's SMTP server

Tags: email, java, mysql, smtp

I'm having a trouble sending an email using Google's SMTP Server. I've looked for a solution but i have not found one. So here's the code.

```
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

...
...
...
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
{                                         
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("true", "mail.smtp.auth");
props.put("true","mail.smtp.starttls.enable");
props.put("smtp.gmail.com", "mail.smtp.host");
props.put("587", "mail.smtp.port");

Session sess=Session.getDefaultInstance(props,
        new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication(){
            return new PasswordAuthentication("myemail@gmail.com", "mypassword");
            }
        }
);
try{
    Message message= new MimeMessage(sess);
    message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("myemail@gmail.com"));
    message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,InternetAddress.parse("myemail@gmail.com"));
    message.setSubject("message");
    message.setText("text");
    Transport.send(message);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sent!");
}catch(Exception e){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
}
```

Each time when i press the button, it show me this error:

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: localhost, port: 25;
nested exception is:
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

I've tried 3 ports: 25, 465, 587 , but it always gives me that error. I even made new rules for the port 25 to the firewall settings, but that doesn't seem to do the trick. Any thoughts what am i doing wrong? Could hibernate cause the problem? Because i'm using it in this project. Plus, i have installed mysql.

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/java/javamail-api-sending-email-via-gmail-smtp-example/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program is trying to connect to a local port, that's why it failed. If your listing is real code, you got the key and value backwards in the props.set statements.